# Problem with prototypal inheritance and instance array

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, node.js

I use prototypal inheritance and want to have objects with instance arrays. So if I derive some objects from one object with an instance array and access the array, all of them share the array. I want to push something to the array and only change the array in the actual object, not in all others.

What is a elegent solution to this Problem with using standard prototypal inheritance and Object.create?

```
var sys = require('sys');

var obj ={
    data: [],
    add: function(what){
        this.data.push(what)
    }
};

var one = Object.create(obj);
one.add(1);

var other = Object.create(obj);
other.add(2);

sys.puts(other.data.length); // is 2, but should be 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ObjectName = function(){
    this.data = [];
}

ObjectName.prototype.add = function(what){
    this.data.push(what);
};

var one = new ObjectName();
one.add(1);
```

Comment: I want to use prototypal inheritence with Object.create

Comment: You can still use object.create.  But you have to run the constructor to initialize the object with the instance variable this.data.

var one = Object.create(ObjectName.prototype);
ObjectName.call(one);

one.add(1);

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant solution with `Object.create`, because You're Doing It Wrong.

What you want is:

```
function MyArray() {
    this.data = [];  // per-instance data here
}

MyArray.prototype = {
    add: function(what) {  // prototype methods here
        this.data.push(what);
    }
};

var one = new MyArray;
one.add(1);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace:

```
add: function(what) {  // prototype methods here
    this.data.push(what);
}
```

with

```
add: function(what) {  // prototype methods here
    this.data = this.data.concat(what);
}
```

as this will create a new variable instead of pushing it into it the prototype's instance.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create` can add properties to the new object, by passing a second parameter with property descriptors.

```
var sys = require('sys');

var obj = {
    add: function(what){
        this.data.push(what)
    }
};

var one = Object.create(obj, {
    data: {
        value: [],
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});
one.add(1);

var other = Object.create(obj, {
    data: {
        value: [],
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});
other.add(2);

sys.puts(other.data.length); // should be 1
```

Of course, you would want to put that in a builder function so you don't repeat yourself:

```
function makeThing() {
    return Object.create(obj, {
        data: {
            value: [],
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
}
```

Although, at at point you're basically writing a constructor (with the advantage that you don't need to call it with new). Also, if you're setting `writable`, `enumerable`, and `configurable` to `true`, you could just set the property the normal way, which can be made backward-compatible with ECMAScript 3 by implementing a simple version of `Object.create`:

```
function makeThing() {
    var newObj = Object.create(obj);
    newObj.data = [];
    return newObj;
}
```